# how to get String from Observable<any> in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot

I have a backend Rest service that returns a string:

```
@GetMapping("/role/{id}")
    public String trouverRole (@PathVariable("id") String username) {
    User u= userrepository.findByUsername(username);
    return u.getRoles().get(0).getName();

    }
```

I'm trying to get the string and use it in angular .ts file:
My service code:

```
getrole(name: string): Observable<any> {

    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/role/'+name);

  }
```

My .ts code:

```
login(){
    this.loginService.authentificate(this.credentials,()=>{

     this.loginService.getrole(this.credentials.username).subscribe(
      data => {
      this.role=JSON.stringify(data);
   });

      if ( this.role=="ROLE_ADMIN" )
          { this.router.navigateByUrl('/home/(contentOutlet:produit)');}

          else console.log(this.role);
          /*
      else 
      { this.router.navigateByUrl('/home/(contentOutlet:dashboard)')}*/
    })

  }
```

I'm getting this error:

"Unexpected token R in JSON at position 0"

Comment: Please paste a code that you tried. Since this is how the SO works. Thanks.

Comment: what you get in response ..?

Comment: Why don´t you simply return an Observable<string> from your Service?

Comment: that's what I get when I change it to Observable<string>:                                                     Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<string>'

Comment: can you give an example of what your API returns ? it seems it does not simply return a string.

Comment: yes the return type of my api is Observable<Object> and I'm trying to get the string from it  but I couldn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
So I was  supposed to specify the return type  by adding:
 {responseType: 'text'}

My service after changes:

```
    getrole(name: string): Observable<any> {

        return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/role/'+name,{responseType: 
   'text'});

      }
```

And no need to use JSON.stringify, writing this.role=data; is the correct thing to do

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have some errors in your code:

```
login(){
    this.loginService.authentificate(this.credentials,()=>{
        this.loginService
               .getrole(this.credentials.username)
               .subscribe(data => {
                  this.role = data // No need to stringify, your response (i am asuming) is a text
        });

    // This will allways return false as this.role is still undefined
      if (this.role === "ROLE_ADMIN")
         this.router.navigateByUrl('/home/(contentOutlet:produit)');
      else 
         console.log(this.role);
    })

  }
```

So to start, `Unexpected token R in JSON at position 0` is thrown because you are using `JSON.stringfy()` which is fundtion that takes a json object and return a json string. your back-end retruns a string so this function will throw an Error.

then, for the part where you check the `this.role`, the `this.role` will not be set until the REST API response. so you should write your code like this.

```
.subscribe(data => {
    this.role = data;
    // here you are sure that the role is set to what you are expecting
    // TODO: <-- HERE YOU PUT YOUR CODE THAT DEPENDS ON "ROLE"
});
```

Comment: the main problem was that my response is not a text, I solved that you can check my answer